# Finding the mean of all Duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

There is a nice explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/how-do-i-remove-all-but-one-specific-duplicate-record-in-an-r-data-frame) describing how to eliminate duplicates in a data frame by picking the maximum variable. 

 I can also see how this can be applied to pick the duplicate with the minimum variable.

 my question now is how do I display the **mean** of all duplicates?

for example:

```
z <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4),var=c(2,4,1,3,5,2))
# id var
#  1   2
#  1   4
#  2   1
#  2   3
#  3   5
#  4   2
```

I would like the output:

```
# id var
#  1   3     mean(2,4)
#  2   2     mean(1,3)
#  3   5
#  4   2
```

My current code is:

```
averages<-do.call(rbind,lapply(split(z,z$id),function(chunk) mean(chunk$var)))
z<-z[order(z$id),]
z<-z[!duplicated(z$id),]
z$var<-averages
```

My code runs very slowly and is takes about 10 times longer than the method for picking the maximum. How do I optimize this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of `ave` and `unique`:

```
z <- data.frame(id=rep(c(1,1,2,2,3,4),1e5),var=rnorm(6e5))
z$var <- ave(z$var, z$id, FUN=mean)
z <- unique(z)
```

UPDATE: after actually timing the solution, here's something that's a little faster.

```
z <- data.frame(id=rep(c(1,1,2,2,3,4),1e5),var=rnorm(6e5))
system.time({
  averages <- t(sapply(split(z,z$id), function(x) sapply(x,mean)))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.32    0.00    1.33 
system.time({
  z$var <- ave(z$var, z$id, FUN=mean)
  z <- unique(z)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    4.33    0.02    4.37
```

Comment: do you know if unique is faster or has any advantage over duplicated?

Comment: @Ellipsis...: you're welcome.  See my update for a solution that's faster (given my tests).

Comment: =/ unfortunately the split method does not work as well for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a faster solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
z <- data.frame(id=sample(letters, 6e5, replace = TRUE),var = rnorm(6e5))

fn1 <- function(z){
  z$var <- ave(z$var, z$id, FUN=mean)
  return(unique(z))
}

fn2 <- function(z) {
  t(sapply(split(z,z$id), function(x) sapply(x,mean)))
}

fn3 <- function(z){
  data.table(z)[,list(var = mean(var)), 'id']
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1 <- fn1(z), f2 <- fn2(z), f3 <- fn3(z), replications = 2)

  est replications elapsed         relative     user.self  sys.self 
1 f1 <- fn1(z)            2   3.619 8.455607     3.331    0.242          
2 f2 <- fn2(z)            2   0.586 1.369159     0.365    0.220          
3 f3 <- fn3(z)            2   0.428 1.000000     0.341    0.086
```

Comment: Since when is 0.428 "much faster" than 0.586? ;-)  The fastest solution will depend on the OP's data, but my bet would be on data.table.

Comment: point taken and edit made! i pasted the output while my daughter was screaming to be picked up :)

Comment: Thanks for this but the ave method works the fastest for me since my data doesn't have huge clusters of duplicates

Answer (score 4):

I think `split()` and `unsplit()` is one way.

```
dupMean <- function(x)
{
    result <- split(x[, 2], x[, 1])
    result <- lapply(result, mean)
    result <- unsplit(result, unique(x[, 1]))

    return(result)  
}
```

Or, to save a line with plyr:

```
require(plyr)
dupMean <- function(x)
{
    result <- split(x[, 2], x[, 1])
    result <- laply(result, mean)

    return(result)  
}
```

***Update:***
Just for curiosity, here is a comparison of the various functions suggested.  Ramnath (fn3) looks to be the winner on my computer.

```
require(plyr)
require(data.table)
require(rbenchmark)

fn1 <- function(z){
    z$var <- ave(z$var, z$id, FUN=mean)
    return(unique(z))
}

fn2 <- function(z) {
    t(sapply(split(z,z$id), function(x) sapply(x,mean)))
}

fn3 <- function(z){
    data.table(z)[,list(var = mean(var)), 'id']
}

fn4 <- function(x)
{
    result <- t(sapply(split(x,x$id), function(y) sapply(y,mean)))

    return(result)
}

fn5 <- function(x)
{
    x$var <- ave(x$var, x$id, FUN=mean)
    x <- unique(x)

    return(x)
}

fn6 <- function(x)
{
    result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(x,x$id),function(chunk) mean(chunk$var)))

    return(data.frame(id = unique(x[, 1]), var = result))
}

fn7 <- function(x)
{
    result <- split(x[, 2], x[, 1])
    result <- lapply(result, mean)
    result <- unsplit(result, unique(x[, 1]))


    return(data.frame(id = unique(x[, 1]), var = result))   
}


fn8 <- function(x)
{
    result <- split(x[, 2], x[, 1])
    result <- laply(result, mean)

    return(data.frame(id = unique(x[, 1]), var = result))
}



z <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7), 1e5), var = rnorm(1e6))

benchmark(f1 <- fn1(z), f2 <- fn2(z), f3 <- fn3(z), f4 <- fn4(z), f5 <- fn5(z), f6 <- fn6(z), f7 <- fn7(z), f8 <- fn8(z), replications = 2)
```

Result:

```
          test replications elapsed  relative user.self sys.self
1 f1 <- fn1(z)            2   13.45 20.692308     13.27     0.15
2 f2 <- fn2(z)            2    3.54  5.446154      3.43     0.09
3 f3 <- fn3(z)            2    0.65  1.000000      0.54     0.10
4 f4 <- fn4(z)            2    3.62  5.569231      3.50     0.09
5 f5 <- fn5(z)            2   13.57 20.876923     13.25     0.25
6 f6 <- fn6(z)            2    3.53  5.430769      3.36     0.14
7 f7 <- fn7(z)            2    3.34  5.138462      3.28     0.03
8 f8 <- fn8(z)            2    3.34  5.138462      3.26     0.03
```

Comment: isn't your first solution pretty much what I have?

Comment: Using `unsplit()` cuts the time in half, compared to `rbind()`.  But Joshua's is much much faster. Testing a data frame with 10^7 rows, total elapsed time was 9.83, 4.70, 0, respectively.